# RavenDB namespace change on document object throws "Unable to cast object" Error

Tags: c#, ravendb

So I am just trying to get RavenDB up and running and I have struggled with several issues but finally got it working. I was able to successfully insert and pull records for display.

However, I decided to move the class I was using to generate documents from to another spot which cause a namespace change. I ran ran everything and I can still insert documents to Raven. But when I try to pull them for display purposes I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Library.Logging.RewardProviderLog' to type 'Admin.ViewModels.ImportMonitorViewModel'.

So after going through all of the other posts I could find online it seems that the issue has something to do with the Raven-Clr-Type that essentially tracks the namespace information of the object you are saving as a document.

Ok. So I went in and deleted all the documents I created since I am still just testing and trying to get things running. I even went ahead and blew away the index and recreated it. I ran my process of inserting a new log. But I still get the same error message when I try to pull them and display them.

Note: ViewModels.ImportMonitorViewModel and Library.Logging.RewardProviderLog are identical. They contain the exact same properties.

**Update**

*Index (named ImportMonitorLogs):*

```
from doc in docs.RewardProviderLogs 
select new {doc.status, doc.newItemsCount, doc.additionalInfo, doc.lastRun};
```

*Query:*

```
DocumentStore RavenDBStore = new Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore { Url = "myurl" };
RavenDBStore.DefaultDatabase = "yei-logs";
RavenDBStore.Initialize();Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), RavenDBStore);

        using(var session = RavenDBStore.OpenSession())
        {
            model = (from log in session.Query<ViewModels.ImportMonitorViewModel>("ImportMonitorLogs")
                     orderby log.lastRun descending
                     select log).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the query (and index) that throws this error? My guess is that you aren't storing a viewmodel in your database, so you probably need help with transformations or projections, but I can't see your code... :)

Comment: I added the index and the query I am using. But like I said it **all worked** right up until I changed the namespace of my class to Library.Logging.RewardProviderLog. Blowing away all documents and indexes in RaveDB didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the rename and what might have worked before, the error matches the query you are attempting.  You are indexing documents of type `RewardProviderLog`, and retrieving them directly as type `ImportMonitorViewModel`.

You say all of the properties are the same in both classes, but that alone won't get RavenDB to duck-type them for you.  You have to be a little more explicit.  This will probably work:

```
model = (from log in session.Query<RewardProviderLog>("ImportMonitorLogs")
         orderby log.lastRun descending
         select log).As<ViewModels.ImportMonitorViewModel>().ToList();
```

Or if you want slightly cleaner syntax (IMHO), this is equivalent:

```
model = session.Query<RewardProviderLog>("ImportMonitorLogs")
               .OrderByDescending(x=> x.lastRun)
               .As<ViewModels.ImportMonitorViewModel>()
               .ToList();
```

The key here is that you are querying based on the type that matches the entity your index is returning, and that you use the `As` method to duck-type it into your view model.  (This is the same thing as `OfType<T>`, and you can read more in the docs [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/results-transformation/of-type?version=2.0)).

If you want to get a bit fancier and project different fields or project from the index directly, you can look at `AsProjection` in the docs [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/results-transformation/project-from-index-fields-into).

If you're still scratching your head as to why this worked before, I can see that it might have worked if your viewmodel an entity were named the same thing - even if they were from different namespaces.  They would still have the same `Raven-Entity-Name` metadata value.

Comment: The MVC portion of my application doesnt know what RewardProviderLogs are. The project doesnt have references to the Logging library and it would be inappropriate in our cade to add them. So we dont really have the option of doing a session.Query <RewardProviderLog>(). Isn't the fact that the Index is returning a select new {...} mean that the type being returned is anonymous?  Shouldn't you be able to pull the JSON into an object with matchin properties?

Comment: Try using your `ViewModels.ImportMonitorViewModel` class in both places.  It will look weird, but I think it will work. The `As` statement must still be there.

Comment: No. :-( It didn't work. Also the As<T> seems not to exist. I had to use OfType<T>

Comment: Hmmm.. It should have.  Maybe check your using statements?  Sometimes I get these mixed up. Perhaps AsProjection would work better.

Comment: Adding `.AsProjection<ViewModels.ImportMonitorViewModel>()` worked.